# The emulator runs slow

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Recently I started to learn Android programming. I instaled Eclipse and Android SDK. All goes well, but every time when I run a project which has a error, the emulator and Eclipse begins to run very hard and I often have to close Eclips and the emulator.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If your project has an error, then eclipse won't let you run the project at all. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The Emulator is notoriously slow. There's only two answers to this questions. 1) Something about your app is bad, 2) the emulator is just being the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this before, but it might help you too. 
I prefere using the the [Bluestacks Player](http://bluestacks.com/). It runs Android 2.3.4 and is very fluent and fast. Sometimes even faster than a normal device. The only downsize is, that you can just test Apps on the API Level 10 and just on one screen size, but it's perfect just for testing if it's working or not. Just connect the Player with the `adb` by running

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

After compiling it installs instantly. Very impressive, considering I have a rather average computer hardware(dual core with 4 GB of RAM)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Do a quick google search for "how to make the Android emulator run faster" (or something along those lines), because you are definitely not the first person to ask this question.
2. Buy a cheap, physical device to test with. It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close the emulator in order to iterate your development cycle. That should speed things up a lot for you. You can also enable emulator snapshots, so the emulator will start up quickly the next time. (It does slow down closing the emulator, however).

The other thing is, though, if your machine is underpowered or does not have sufficient RAM, it could be thrashing. Eclipse and the Android emulator do require a fair amount of memory. Ideally, you should have at least 500MB of free memory before starting Eclipse (1GB would be better).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when you always install and re-install apps on the emulator to test, it gets clogged up and starts lagging. 
Solution: Delete the AVD you have created from the Virtual Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

`Goto to your BIOS settings. Enable your Virtualization technology in your settings..`

It solved my problem...